# Visual Studio 2015 could not deduce template argument (error C2784)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I have a simple method that takes container and concatenates its content into single string:

```
namespace util {

    template <template <typename, typename...> class C, typename T>
    std::string to_string( const C<T> & elements, const std::string & separator = " " ) {
        std::stringstream xml;
        std::for_each( elements.begin(), elements.end(), [&]( const T & element ) {
            xml << element << separator;
        } );
        std::string result = xml.str();
        return result.substr( 0, result.size() - separator.size() );
    }

}
```

and use it like this:

```
util::to_string( std::vector<int>({ 1, 3, 5 }) );
std::list<std::string> list = { "a", "b", "c" };
util::to_string( list );
```

and it has been working fine with GCC, however when I compile with 
Visual Studio 2015 it gives these errors:

```
error C2672: 'util::to_string': no matching overloaded function found
error C2784: 'std::string util::to_string(const C<T,> &,const std::string &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const C<T,> &' from 'std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
```

and MSDN is no help either: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wf867f8f.aspx

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 1

Comment: `string` or `to_string`?

Comment: Looks like a bug/incomplete feature with variadic templates, to me.

Comment: Try `template <template <typename, typename...> class C, typename T, class...Ts>` then `const C<T,Ts...> & elements`.  However, being a template of one argument is a poor pattern to match being a container.

Comment: That solved it. Thanks Yakk!